# Msgbox Yes No & cancel button working in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, msgbox

Below is my code for a MsgBox. The *Yes* button is working, but when I click *No* or *Cancel* it still deletes the data...

```
        strup = "DELETE FROM student WHERE urno =" & CInt(txtUrn.Text) & ";"
        Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strup, con)
        MsgBox("Do you want to delete record(s)", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Confirm Delete")
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
```

How do I have it cancel the delete operation when clicking *No* or *Cancel*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the basic `If` statement to check the return value of `MsgBox`. The `MsgBox` doesn't cancel anything by itself.

```
If MsgBox("Prompt", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Title") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    ' execute command
End If
```

You could also use `MsgBoxStyle.YesNo` to get only the Yes and No buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to `If...Then`, but I think this is cleaner

```
Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Delete")
    Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
        ' Do something if yes
    Case MsgBoxResult.No
        ' Do something if no
End Select
```

Comment: By the way, you should be using the .NET equivalent, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show() instead of MsgBox. Although they both point to the .NET version, we have moved to .NET and there are few reasons to hold on to VB6 syntax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799976/is-there-any-difference-between-msgbox-and-messagebox-show

Answer (score 0):

```
        If MsgBox("Are you sure ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Delete") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            strup = "DELETE FROM student WHERE urno =" & CInt(txtUrn.Text) & ";"
            Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strup, con)
            'MsgBox("Do you want to delete record(s)", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Confirm Delete")
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            txtUrn.Text = ""
            txt10Per.Text = ""
            txt12Per.Text = ""
            txtCAdd.Text = ""
            txtEid.Text = ""
            txtFname.Text = ""
            txtGPer.Text = ""
            txtMno.Text = ""
            txtName.Text = ""
            txtPAdd.Text = ""
            cmb10YofPass.Text = ""
            cmb12YofPass.Text = ""
            cmbDate.Text = ""
            cmbGender.Text = ""
            cmbMonth.Text = ""
            cmbNameofGCourse.Text = ""
            cmbYear.Text = ""
            ComboBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            MsgBox("Record Deleted Successfully")
        ElseIf MsgBoxResult.No Then

        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Still a MsgBox will not work in an ASP.NET production environment or QA rather than development environment.